# Angular Universal SSR ReferenceError: Element is not defined

Tags: angular

I've got an error during npm run serve:ssr with Angular 9.

C:\Projects\gloffice-client-ui-apela\dist\general-ledger-office-server\main.js:362348
Element.prototype.matches ||
^

ReferenceError: Element is not defined
at Object.p4r7 (C:\Projects\gloffice-client-ui-apela\dist\general-ledger-office-server\main.js:362348:3)
at **webpack_require** (C:\Projects\gloffice-client-ui-apela\dist\general-ledger-office-server\main.js:20:30)
at Object.47Jg (C:\Projects\gloffice-client-ui-apela\dist\general-ledger-office-server\main.js:66309:27)
at **webpack_require** (C:\Projects\gloffice-client-ui-apela\dist\general-ledger-office-server\main.js:20:30)
at Object.wCP4 (C:\Projects\gloffice-client-ui-apela\dist\general-ledger-office-server\main.js:437789:27)
at **webpack_require** (C:\Projects\gloffice-client-ui-apela\dist\general-ledger-office-server\main.js:20:30)
at Object.ZAI4 (C:\Projects\gloffice-client-ui-apela\dist\general-ledger-office-server\main.js:307442:24)
at **webpack_require** (C:\Projects\gloffice-client-ui-apela\dist\general-ledger-office-server\main.js:20:30)
at Object.24aS (C:\Projects\gloffice-client-ui-apela\dist\general-ledger-office-server\main.js:61326:20)
at **webpack_require** (C:\Projects\gloffice-client-ui-apela\dist\general-ledger-office-server\main.js:20:30)

Any idea on how to fix this error? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you've provided seems to be coming from some 3d party library, which is not adjusted to work with Universal and uses *window* or *document* object driectly.
From the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/universal#working-around-the-browser-apis):

> Because a Universal app doesn't execute in the browser, some of the
> browser APIs and capabilities may be missing on the server. For
> example, server-side applications can't reference browser-only global
> objects such as *window*, *document*, *navigator*, or *location*.

After working with several projects using Angular Universal I wrote a list of gotchas that can help you: http://michaelborisov.com/blog

Answer (score 0):

According to our friend's answer, it should be clear that our browser is ready

```
import { PLATFORM_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser} from '@angular/common';

export class MyComponent {
browserIsReady: boolean;
constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: string) {
        this.browserIsReady = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
        if (this.browserIsReady) {
            //this is only executed on the browser
        }
}
```